# Menu admin Django

Tags: django

En el panel de administracion de Django, en el template, tengo un código para reproducir de forma dinàmica los enlaces a los modelos de las app que tengo registradas en admin.py. Funciona bien dentro http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin

```
{% for model in app.models %}                        
      {% if model.admin_url %}
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview menu-open">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="{{ model.admin_url }}" class="nav-link">
                             <i class="nav-icon fas fa-circle"></i> {{ model.name }}
                         </a>
                  </li>
            </ul>
      {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

El problema me surge cuando al navegar al directorio de alguna app que tengo, por ejemplo http://127.0.0.1:8000/facturacion/ el menú de administracion no sé muestra... Utilizo el template AdminLTE3.

Gracias!